# jQuery ajax async logic

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery 1.7 so this should not be a async deprecated problem. So this is the story what I had:

```
LunchTime()
{
    CheckMoney();
    if(confirm('leaving office?'))
    {
        // async:false, an ajax call and continue...
        // below code are in "success"
        if(DoneWithLunch())
        {
            if(moneyInWallet < bill) { alert('how can you eat without money?');}
        }
    }
}

CheckMoney()
{
    // async:false, ajax call to check if I have money
    // code below are in "success"
    if(moneyInWallet < 1) { window.location = 'YourCube.html';}
}
```

so every lunch time, I should check for money, and if I don't then I should stay in my cube (and no lunch for me. [how sad]). The problem is I always go out and have lunch with no money, should CheckMoney() stop me before I head out? (Ends up I have to stay and do dishes in the restaurant and skip work).

Any clue that I might do wrong?

----- edit -----

so I came down to this:

```
$(function ()
{
    go();
    alert('end');
});

function go()
{
    window.location = 'home.html';
}
```

but it alert 'end' then redirect. why?

Comment: Have you considered debugging? Start by checking the value of `moneyInWallet`.

Comment: yes, tried the debugging, it seems that window.location should take place but it didn't.

Comment: @Jim you spelled window.location wrong

Comment: haha... yes, let me correct that, it's just a typo. =P
but in my code it spells correct